# Multi-language integration problem with FlatBuffers

Tags: c++, go, multilingual, flatbuffers

## Question

I have a recurring crash (`panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range`) from the `flatbuffers` generated server files when attempting to access a part of a buffer (created with `flatbuffers`) which contains a message streamed from one client to a server.
This problem only appears in integration of both client and server. When tested on their own, both client and server succeed in using `flatbuffers` and no crash occurs in the server `// see the boundary tests below`
Knowing that:
 - the sent and received `byte[]` is the same, (which excludes a problem in the communication method)
 - the sent data is correctly formed before it is put in the `flatbuffers`' `buffer` and sent.
What could be causing this?

## Problem context and details

I have a `c++` **client** and a `go` **server** that communicate using `FlatBuffers`.
The **client** and **server** both have automated boundary-tests which confirm that they each "correctly" use `flatbuffers` the way they should. (i.e. the **client** creates the buffer before sending it and the **server** receives before access it)
These tests work.
We are using `FlatBuffers-v1.10.0`

My problem is that when they are used together, the following error always occurs in the **server** when accessing to the buffer:

```
panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range  

goroutine 19 [running]:
github.com/google/flatbuffers/go.(*Table).GetVOffsetT(...)
     /home/.../go/github.com/google/flatbuffers/go/table.go:134
github.com/google/flatbuffers/go.(*Table).OffsetT(0x4000045c68, 0x4000000004, 0x4000160008)
     /home/.../go/github.com/google/flatbuffers/go/table.go:16 +0xf0
github.com/PhantomIntelligence/Server/lib/Protocol/Stream.(*StreamedData).Id(0x4000045c68, 0x4000045c68)
     /home/.../go/github.com/PhantomIntelligence/Server/lib/Protocol/Stream/SteamedData.go:30 +0x2c
github.com/PhantomIntelligence/Server/dataAccess/conversion/flatBuffers.ConvertStreamMessage(0x4000015a000, 0xa7c, 0xe00, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
     /home/.../go/github.com/PhantomIntelligence/Server/dataAccess/conversion/flatBuffers/deserialization.go:55 +0x1fc
... // the rest is irrelevant for this question's purpose
```

### Data causing the crash

The crash always happen on the first buffer received by the server when it tries to access it to use it. More specifically, it always happen when attempting to access the either the (0th, 12th or 15th) `ContainerData` of the 7th `Container`.

> Know that for this use case, we send a *StreamedData* with 16 *Containers*, each holding 16 *ContainerData*

---

## Code details

> Note that only the structure is remains from my original implementation. I am not allowed to divulgate the nature of the data we manipulate. Thus the object names might seem weird, but the structure is the relevant part.

### Schema compilation

The `c++` **client** runs this during its compilation:

```
flatc -o lib/ --no-js-exports --no-prefix --scoped-enums --cpp schemas/*.fbs
```

The `go` **server** runs this during its compilation:

```
flatc -o lib/ --no-js-exports --no-prefix --scoped-enums --go schemas/*.fbs
```

### Schemas

Both the **client** and **server** use the following schema:

> Please note that this extract is not the complete schema, only the part relevant for this question.

```
// file: stream_streamed_data.fbs
namespace Protocol.Stream;
table ContainerData {
  id:uint16 = 0;
  a:uint16 = 0;
  b:uint16 = 0;
  c:int16 = 0;
  d:int16 = 0;
  e:uint8 = 0;
}
table Container {
  id:uint16 = 65535;
  data:[ContainerData];
}
table StreamedData {
  id:uint16 = 0;
  containers:[Container];
}
---- 
// file: stream_payload.fbs
include "stream_streamed_data.fbs";
/* some more includes ... */

namespace Protocol.Stream;
union PayloadContent { StreamedData, ..., Request, Result } 

table Payload {
  sensor_id:string;
  content:PayloadContent;
}

---- 
// file: header.fbs

namespace Protocol;
table Header {
  source_id:string;
  destination_id:string;
  timestamp:string;
}

---- 
// file: protocol_message.fbs
include "headers.fbs";
include "stream_payload.fbs";
/* some more includes ... */

namespace Protocol;
union Content { Stream.Payload, ..., Other.Payload } 

table Message {
  header:Header;
  content:Content;
}

root_type Message;
```

The **client** has to stream `Protocol.Message`s that contain `Protocol.Stream.Payload`, which themselves contain a `Protocol.Stream.StreamedMessage`.

### **Client** implementation

```
#ifndef CLIENT_FLATBUFFERSCONVERTER_HPP
#define CLIENT_FLATBUFFERSCONVERTER_HPP

#include <flatbuffers/flatbuffers.h>
#include <lib/protocol/protocol_message_generated.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

namespace ServerCommunication {

    enum class ProtocolStructure : uint8_t {
        NONE = 0,
        /* some more types ... */

        SENSOR_MESSAGE = 12,

        /* some more types ... */

        UNRECOGNIZED_TYPE = // A NUMBER,
        MIN = NONE,
        MAX = UNRECOGNIZED_TYPE
    };

    typedef uint8_t* FlatBuffersBytes;

    struct BytesToSend {
        FlatBuffersBytes data;
        size_t dataLength;
    };

    namespace BufferSize {
        size_t const STREAMED_MESSAGE = 2560;
    }

    template<class T>
    class FlatBuffersConverter {

    public:

        explicit FlatBuffersConverter() = delete;

        ~FlatBuffersConverter() noexcept = delete;

        FlatBuffersConverter(FlatBuffersConverter const& other) = delete;

        FlatBuffersConverter(FlatBuffersConverter&& other) noexcept = delete;

        FlatBuffersConverter& operator=(FlatBuffersConverter const& other)& = delete;

        FlatBuffersConverter& operator=(FlatBuffersConverter&& other)& noexcept = delete;

        static BytesToSend const convertSensorMessage(typename T::Message&& message) noexcept;

    private:

        static std::string const generateSerializationTimestamp() noexcept;


    };

    template<class T>
    BytesToSend const FlatBuffersConverter<T>::convertStreamMessage(typename T::StreamMessage&& message) noexcept {
        flatbuffers::FlatBufferBuilder builder(BufferSize::STREAM_MESSAGE);

        auto streamIdFromMessage = message.getStreamId();
        auto streamId = builder.CreateString(streamIdFromMessage.c_str(), streamIdFromMessage.size());
        auto source = streamId;
        auto destination = builder.CreateString("Server");
        auto timestamp = builder.CreateString(generateSerializationTimestamp());
        auto header = Protocol::CreateHeader(
                builder,
                source,
                destination,
                timestamp);

        auto containersFromStreamMessage = message.getContainers();
        std::vector<flatbuffers::Offset<Protocol::Stream::Container>> containerVector;
        auto containerIterator = containersFromStreamMessage->begin();
        auto containerEnd = containersFromStreamMessage->end();

        for (; containerIterator != containerEnd; ++containerIterator) {

            auto dataFromContainer = containerIterator->getData();
            std::vector<flatbuffers::Offset<GatewayProtocol::Stream::ContainerData>> containerDataVector;
            auto containerDataIterator = dataFromContainer->begin();
            auto containerDataEnd = dataFromContainer->end();

            for (; containerDataIterator != containerDataEnd; ++containerDataIterator) {
                auto track = Protocol::Stream::CreateContainerData(
                        builder,
                        containerDataIterator->id,
                        containerDataIterator->a,
                        containerDataIterator->b,
                        containerDataIterator->c,
                        containerDataIterator->d,
                        containerDataIterator->e);
                containerDataVector.push_back(containerData);
            }

            auto containerDataFBVector = builder.CreateVector(containerDataVector);

            auto container = Protocol::Stream::CreateContainer(
                    builder,
                    containerIterator->id,
                    containerDataFBVector);
            containerVector.push_back(container);
        }

        auto containers = builder.CreateVector(containerVector);
        auto streamMessageContent = Protocol::Stream::CreateStreamedData(
                builder,
                message.messageId,
                containers);

        auto streamPayload = Protocol::Stream::CreatePayload(
                builder,
                streamId,
                Protocol::Stream::PayloadContent::StreamedData,
                streamMessageContent.Union());

        auto convertedMessage = Protocol::CreateMessage(
                builder,
                header,
                Protocol::Content::Stream_Payload,
                sensorPayload.Union());

        builder.Finish(convertedMessage);

        auto size = builder.GetSize();
        auto data = builder.GetBufferPointer();
        BytesToSend bytesToSend{data, size};
        return bytesToSend;
    }

    template<class T>
    std::string const FlatBuffersConverter<T>::generateSerializationTimestamp() noexcept {
        std::size_t const ARBITRARY_BIG_ENOUGH_SIZE = 128;
        auto timestamp = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto time_tTimestamp = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(timestamp);
        auto utcTime = gmtime(&time_tTimestamp);
        char charArrayTime[ARBITRARY_BIG_ENOUGH_SIZE];
        auto numberOfCharacterWritten = strftime(charArrayTime, sizeof(charArrayTime), "%D %T", utcTime);
        std::string formattedTime(std::begin(charArrayTime), std::begin(charArrayTime) + numberOfCharacterWritten);
        return formattedTime;
    }

}

#endif //CLIENT_FLATBUFFERSCONVERTER_HPP
```

### **Client** Boundary test

```
#ifndef CLIENT_SERVERCOMMUNICATORTEST_CPP
#define CLIENT_SERVERCOMMUNICATORTEST_CPP

#include <gtest/gtest.h>

/* some other include */
#include "spirit-sensor-gateway/server-communication/WebSocketServerCommunicationStrategy.hpp"
#include "test/utilities/stub/WebSocketServerStub.h" // <--- Receives and accesses the buffer

using ServerCommunication::WebSocketServerCommunicationStrategy;
using Stub::WebSocketServerStub;
using TestFunctions::DataTestUtil;

class WebSocketServerCommunicatorTest : public ::testing::Test {
protected:
};

TEST_F(WebSocketServerCommunicatorTest, given_aNumberOfRandomStreamDataMessage_when_send_then_theDataIsPutInFlatBuffersAndReceivedByTheServer) {

    auto numberOfMessageToSend = 10;

    WebSocketServerStub webSocketServerStub;

    WebSocketServerCommunicationStrategy<Sensor::Test::ServerLike::Structures> webSocketServerCommunicationStrategy;
    webSocketServerStub.run();
    webSocketServerCommunicationStrategy.openConnection(webSocketServerStub.getAddress());

    ServerStructuresLists::StreamDataMessages sentStreamDataMessages;

    for (auto i = 0; i < numberOfMessageToSend; i++) {
        auto streamDataMessage = DataTestUtil::createRandomStreamDataMessage();
        auto streamDataMessageCopy = DataModel::StreamDataMessage(streamDataMessage);

        sentStreamDataMessages.push_back(std::move(streamDataMessageCopy));
        webSocketServerCommunicationStrategy.sendMessage(std::move(streamDataMessage));
    }

    auto numberOfReceivedMessages = webSocketServerStub.getNumberOfMessageReceived();
    while(numberOfMessageToSend != numberOfReceivedMessages) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(50));
        std::this_thread::yield();
        numberOfReceivedMessages = webSocketServerStub.getNumberOfMessageReceived();
    }

    webSocketServerCommunicationStrategy.closeConnection();
    auto receivedStreamDataMessages = webSocketServerStub.getStreamDataMessages();

    auto sameMessageSentAndReceived = sentStreamDataMessages.size() == receivedStreamDataMessages.size();

    for (auto streamDataMessageIndex = 0;
         sameMessageSentAndReceived && streamDataMessageIndex < sentStreamDataMessages.size(); ++streamDataMessageIndex) {
        sameMessageSentAndReceived = sameMessageSentAndReceived &&
                                     sentStreamDataMessages.front() == receivedStreamDataMessages.front();
        sentStreamDataMessages.pop_front();
        receivedStreamDataMessages.pop_front();
    }
    if (!sameMessageSentAndReceived) {
        while (!sentStreamDataMessages.empty() && !receivedStreamDataMessages.empty()) {
            std::cout << "Sent:     " << sentStreamDataMessages.front().toString() << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Received: " << receivedStreamDataMessages.front().toString() << std::endl;
            sentStreamDataMessages.pop_front();
            receivedStreamDataMessages.pop_front();
        }
    }

    ASSERT_TRUE(sameMessageSentAndReceived);
}

#endif //CLIENT_SERVERCOMMUNICATORTEST_CPP
```

### **Client**'s ServerStub FlatBuffer Conversion function

```
#include "ServerStubFlatBuffersConverter.h"

using Stub::ServerFlatBuffersConverter;
using ServerCommunication::ProtocolStructure;

ServerFlatBuffersConverter::StreamDataMessage
ServerFlatBuffersConverter::convertToStreamDataMessage(const ServerCommunication::FlatBuffersBytes flatBuffersBytes) {
    // the identification step has been done at this point, we know the []byte holds a StreamedData
    auto message = Protocol::GetMessage(flatBuffersBytes);
    auto streamDataMessagePayload = message->content_as_Stream_Payload();
    auto streamedData = streamDataMessagePayload->content_as_StreamedData();
    auto messageId = streamedData->id();
    auto streamId = flatbuffers::GetString(streamDataMessagePayload->stream_id());

    auto ContainersBuffer = streamedData->containers();

    std::vector<DataModel::MessageContainer> containers;
    for (flatbuffers::uoffset_t containerIndex = 0;
         containerIndex < ContainersBuffer->Length();
         ++containerIndex) {
        auto containerFromBuffer = ContainersBuffer->Get(containerIndex);

        auto containerId = containerFromBuffer->id();
        auto containerDatasBuffer = containerFromBuffer->data();
        std::vector<DataModel::ContainerData> containerDatas;
        for (auto dataIterator = containerDatasBuffer->begin();
             dataIterator != containerDatasBuffer->end();
             ++dataIterator) {
            auto data = DataModel::ContainerData{
                    dataIterator->id(),
                    dataIterator->a(),
                    dataIterator->b(),
                    dataIterator->c(),
                    dataIterator->d(),
                    dataIterator->e()
            };
            containerDatas.push_back(data);
        }
        auto container = DataModel::MessageContainer(containerId, containerDatas);
        containers.push_back(container);
    }

    StreamDataMessage message(streamId, messageId, containers);
    return message;
}
```

### **Server** Implementation

```
package flatBuffers

import (
    "github.com/PhantomIntelligence/Server/domain/protocol"
    "github.com/PhantomIntelligence/Server/lib/Protocol"
    "github.com/PhantomIntelligence/Server/lib/Protocol/Stream"
    "github.com/google/flatbuffers/go"
)

type GatewayMessageType = byte

const (
    NONE                     = 0
     /* some more types ... */
    SENSOR_MESSAGE           = 12
    /* some more types ... */
    UNRECOGNIZED_TYPE        = // A NUMBER
)

func ConvertStreamMessage(messageBytes []byte) protocol.StreamMessage {
    // the identification step has been done at this point, we know the []byte holds a StreamedData
    var protocolMessageFlatBuffersTable = new(flatbuffers.Table)
    var protocolMessageContentFlatBuffersTable = new(flatbuffers.Table)

    var clientMessageOffset = Protocol.GetRootAsMessage(messageBytes, 0)

    var header = new(Protocol.Header)
    clientMessageOffset.Header(header)
    clientMessageOffset.Content(protocolMessageFlatBuffersTable)

    var messageTimestampString = string(header.Timestamp())

    var streamedPayload = new(Stream.Payload)
    streamedPayload.Init(protocolMessageFlatBuffersTable.Bytes, protocolMessageFlatBuffersTable.Pos)
    streamedPayload.Content(protocolMessageContentFlatBuffersTable)

    var streamIdFromClient = string(streamedPayload.StreamId())

    var streamedDataFromClient = new(Stream.StreamedData)
    streamedDataFromClient.Init(protocolMessageContentFlatBuffersTable.Bytes, protocolMessageContentFlatBuffersTable.Pos)

    var numberOfContainers = streamedDataFromClient.ContainersLength()
    var containers []protocol.Container
    for containerIndex := 0; containerIndex < numberOfContainers; containerIndex++ {
        var containerFromStream = new(Stream.Container)
        streamedDataFromClient.Containers(containerFromStream, containerIndex)

        var numberOfContainerDatas = containerFromStream.ContainerDatasLength()
        var datas []protocol.ContainerData
        for containerDataIndex := 0; containerDataIndex < numberOfContainerDatas; containerDataIndex++ {
            var dataFromContainer = new(Stream.ContainerData)
            containerFromStream.Data(dataFromContainer, dataIndex)
            datas = append(datas, protocol.ContainerData{
                Id:         protocol.IdType(dataFromContainer.Id()), // <--- This line crashes ! always @ containerIndex = 6, containerDataIndex = 0, 12 or 15
                A:        protocol.AType(dataFromContainer.A()),
                B:       protocol.BType(dataFromContainer.B()),
                C:           protocol.CType(dataFromContainer.C()),
                D:    protocol.DType(dataFromContainer.D()),
                E: protocol.EType(dataFromContainer.E()),
            })
        }

        containers = append(containers, protocol.Container{
            ContainerId:               protocol.ContainerIdType(containerFromStream.Id()),
            ContainerDatas:                datas,
        })
    }

    var streamedMessage = protocol.StreamedMessage{
        StreamId:  protocol.SensorIdType(streamIdFromClient),
        MessageId: protocol.MessageIdType(streamedDataFromClient.Id()),
        Containers:    containers,
    }

    return  streamedMessage
}
```

### Server Boundary test

This test pass, we also have a similar test that sends *n* random data instead of 1 and it passes too

```
package receptionFromGateway_test

import (
    "/* some more imports */
    "github.com/PhantomIntelligence/Server/test/utilities/clientStub"
    "os"
    "runtime"
    "testing"
    "time"
)

func TestFlatBuffersReceptionAndAccessFromClient(test *testing.T) {
    defer os.RemoveAll("./logs")

    test.Run("given_aStreamedDataMessageSentFromClientStub"+
        "_when_receivedAndAccessedByServer"+
        "_then_streamedDataMessageIntegrityIsConserved", func(subTest *testing.T) {
        sentStreamedDataMessage := utilities.GenerateRandomStreamedDataMessage(16, 16) // 16 container, 16 data each

        deserializer := serialization.NewFlatBufferDeserializationFilter()
        pipe := dataFlow.NewPipe(deserializer)
        procedure := dataFlowMock.NewProcedurePassToPipeThenSave(pipe)
        pipeline := dataFlow.NewPipeline(procedure)

        client := clientStub.NewWebSocketCommunicator() // <-- this calls  `convertStreamMessageToFlatBuffers` written below
        server := serving.NewServer()
        server.Router.Mediator.Pipeline = pipeline

        go server.Serve(":3591")
        runtime.Gosched()
        time.Sleep(50 * time.Millisecond)
        client.Start()
        client.Send(sentStreamedDataMessage)
        runtime.Gosched()
        time.Sleep(50 * time.Millisecond)
        client.Stop()

        pipeline.GetProducingPipe().TerminateProcess()

        var receivedStreamedDataMessage = pipeline.GetProducingPipe().Filter.(*dataFlowMock.FilterSaveObjectReceived).ObjectReceived
        utilities.AssertEqual(subTest, receivedStreamedDataMessage, sentStreamedDataMessage)
    })
}
```

### Server ClientStub's serialization function

```
package client

Stub

import (
    "github.com/PhantomIntelligence/Server/dataAccess/conversion/flatBuffers"
    "github.com/PhantomIntelligence/Server/domain/protocol"
    "github.com/PhantomIntelligence/Server/lib/Protocol"
    "github.com/PhantomIntelligence/Server/lib/Protocol/Stream"
    "github.com/google/flatbuffers/go"
)

const (
    streamedDataMessageInitialSize = 2560
)

func convertStreamMessageToFlatBuffers(message protocol.StreamMessage) []byte {
    builder := flatbuffers.NewBuilder(streamedDataMessageInitialSize)

    var streamIdOffset = builder.CreateString(string(message.StreamId))

    var headerOffset = createFlatBufferHeaders(builder, streamIdOffset)

    var numberOfContainers int
    var containerOffsets = make(map[int]flatbuffers.UOffsetT)
    for containerIndex, container := range message.Containers {

        var numberOfData int
        var containerDataOffsets = make(map[int]flatbuffers.UOffsetT)
        for containerIndex, container := range container.ContainerDatas {
            Stream.ContainerDataStart(builder)
            Stream.ContainerDataAddId(builder, uint16(container.ContainerDataId))
            Stream.ContainerDataAddA(builder, uint16(container.A))
            Stream.ContainerDataAddB(builder, uint16(container.B))
            Stream.ContainerDataAddC(builder, int16(container.C))
            Stream.ContainerDataAddD(builder, int16(container.D))
            Stream.ContainerDataAddE(builder, byte(container.E))

            containerDataOffset := Stream.ContainerDataEnd(builder)
            containerDataOffsets[containerIndex] = containerDataOffset

            numberOfData = containerIndex + 1
        }

        Stream.ContainerStartDataVector(builder, numberOfData)
        // FlatBuffer UOffsetT vector requires to be filled by pre-pending backward the offsets
        for dataOffsetIndex := numberOfData - 1; dataOffsetIndex >= 0; dataOffsetIndex-- {
            builder.PrependUOffsetT(containerDataOffsets[dataOffsetIndex])
        }
        var dataOffsetVector = builder.EndVector(numberOfData)

        Stream.ContainerStart(builder)
        Stream.ContainerAddId(builder, uint16(container.ContainerId))
        Stream.ContainerAddData(builder, dataOffsetVector)

        containerOffset := Stream.ContainerEnd(builder)
        containerOffsets[containerIndex] = containerOffset

        numberOfContainers = containerIndex + 1
    }

    Stream.StreamedDataStartContainersVector(builder, numberOfContainers)
    // FlatBuffer UOffsetT vector requires to be filled by pre-pending backward the offsets
    for containerOffsetIndex := numberOfContainers - 1; containerOffsetIndex >= 0; containerOffsetIndex-- {
        builder.PrependUOffsetT(containerOffsets[containerOffsetIndex])
    }
    var containerOffsetVector = builder.EndVector(numberOfContainers)

    Stream.StreamedDataStart(builder)
    Stream.StreamedDataAddId(builder, uint16(message.MessageId))
    Stream.StreamedDataAddContainers(builder, containerOffsetVector)
    var streamedDataMessageOffset = Stream.StreamedDataEnd(builder)

    Stream.PayloadStart(builder)
    Stream.PayloadAddSensorId(builder, streamIdOffset)
    Stream.PayloadAddContentType(builder, Stream.PayloadContentStreamedData)
    Stream.PayloadAddContent(builder, streamedDataMessageOffset)
    var streamPayloadOffset = Stream.PayloadEnd(builder)

    Protocol.MessageStart(builder)
    Protocol.MessageAddHeader(builder, headerOffset)
    Protocol.MessageAddContentType(builder, Protocol.ContentStream_Payload)
    Protocol.MessageAddContent(builder, streamPayloadOffset)
    clientStreamMessageOffset := Protocol.MessageEnd(builder)

    builder.Finish(clientStreamMessageOffset)

    flatBuffersBytes := builder.Bytes[builder.Head():]
    return flatBuffersBytes
}

func createFlatBufferHeaders(builder *flatbuffers.Builder, sensorIdOffset flatbuffers.UOffsetT) flatbuffers.UOffsetT {
    destinationIdOffset := builder.CreateString("Server")
    offset := flatBuffers.CreateHeaderOffset(builder, destinationIdOffset, sensorIdOffset)
    return offset
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this the entire problem, but a quick glance at `convertStreamMessage` shows a major problem: the `FlatBufferBuilder` is a local variable which goes out of scope just as you are returning a raw pointer to its internal data which is being destructed.

You either want to make sure the `FlatBufferBuilder` outlives the sending of the data, or use `FlatBufferBuilder::Release()` as the return value instead.

Also note that in debugging these problems, you could have used the C++ verifier (or any code that reads the data) to check the data just before sending it, which would have caught this problem earlier.

Comment: You're totally right on the fact that the local variable goes out of scope.  I added your suggestion to my original code since its certain this is necessary.

Comment: Although your answer did not fix my problem, it prevent a future one. For this I thank you.   
  
It also brought to my attention the buffer and its management.    
I finally solved the problem by increasing the initial buffer size when creating the builder.   
It appears that when the builder resizes the buffer, it looses or does not use the 2 bytes following the end of the original size. I don't know if this is due to a bug or a misuse from my part, but I do not remember reading anything about this in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

> In the end what solved my problem was simply to increase the initial buffer size of the builder in the **client**.
>
> It would appear that immediately when the builder resizes, the 2 bytes positioned next to the end of the initial buffer (before the dynamic resize) were either not used or lost their data.

The test data I was using in the **client** didn't brought this problem forward, it's payload was a bit smaller than the real data we used, so when the test were running, no resize happened.

Although this is the actual solution to my problem, I would not have found it this fast without [@Aardappel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53181712/4522147) , which also prevented an eventual later problem.

Comment: Resizing most definitely does not lose data, it sounds like you have further problems hiding in your code if this happening.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I will investigate further.